# Trouble to understand how networking works on nomad

Tags: nginx, docker, nomad

Can someone explain why I can't access my website running in a docker container thru nomad or what I'm doing wrong ? I'm beginner in system and networking.

I would like to make the container http listen on 127.0.0.1:8088 so that nginx can proxy.

Nomad server and client are running on the same machine

Machine is fedora, disabled SELinux, firewall disabled.

What I expect :
Request to <server_ip>:8088 responds website

What I get :
Response is Connection refused.

nomad conf :

```
data_dir  = "/opt/nomad/data"
bind_addr = "0.0.0.0"
log_level = "DEBUG"

server {
  # license_path is required for Nomad Enterprise as of Nomad v1.1.1+
  #license_path = "/etc/nomad.d/license.hclic"
  enabled          = true
  bootstrap_expect = 1
}
acl {
   enabled = true
}

client {
  enabled = true
  servers = ["127.0.0.1"]
}
```

nomad job :

```
job "ctprods-app" {
  datacenters = ["*"]

  group "ctprods-group" {
    count = 1
    network {
      port "http" {
         static = 8088
         to = 8088
      }
    }
    task "ctprods-task" {
      driver = "docker"
      env {
          ENVIRONMENT = "production"
      }
      config {
        image = "ctaque/ctprods:latest"
        ports = [
          "http"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

nginx block :

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8088/;
}
```

ss -nplut :

```
tcp LISTEN  0  4096 <server_public_ip>:8088 0.0.0.0:*
```

nomad job port map :
[image: nomad job port map]

nomad job running :
[image: nomad job running]